# How to check if a Vector3 or Quaternion are unassigned?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame, serialization

How can I check whether `Vector3` and `Quaternion` are not "null"?

I have a saving system and didn't have a vector and quaternion value before.

Now I've added a `Vector3` and `Quaternion` value into the saving system, so the new save file should have a `Vector3` and `Quaternion` value.

I need to check whether the vector and quaternion values are present in the save file, but I can't use `!= null`, cause it's a struct, so it can't be null.

So how can I check whether the value exists or not?

```
position != Vector3.zero , Rotation != Quaternion.identity
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: `if(x == null)` is the check to see if `x` is null. Your code snippet is checking to see if a position is zero or the rotation is the identity, which is not the same thing as checking for null. Null means 'unassigned value'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `struct` type has not been given any particular value, it will usually default to a special value helpfully called `default`. (Though it's possible the file loading code you use does something different — you haven't shown us, so I'm assuming it's following standard C# convention).

The members of `default` will each hold the value corresponding to the `default` of their respective types: 0 for numbers, `false` for booleans, `null` for reference types, etc.

So you can check:

```
if (!position.Equals(default)) {/*...*/}

if (rotation != default) {/*...*/}
```

For a `Vector3`, the default value is the same as `Vector3.zero`, ie. (0, 0, 0), just less typing, and a bit more explicit that you're checking if it's a default value not looking for a deliberately-set value of zero.

But that highlights a bit of an issue with this code: it won't distinguish between loading an item for which no `position` was set, versus loading an item that was set to `(0, 0, 0)` deliberately.

If that distinction is important for your loading logic, then as others have suggested, you may want to change the declaration of your variable to:

```
[SerializeField]
Vector3? position;
```

This makes it a ["nullable" struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) — it's still a value type, but it gains an extra flag that tracks whether a value has been set.

You can check this with:

```
if (!position.HasValue) {/*...*/}
```

or, for convenience, `position == null` translates to this for nullable types.

Then, to access the `Vector3` contents, you'd write `position.Value`.

You'll note that I used the `.Equals()` method instead of `==` above. That's because the equality operator for `Vector3` has a built-in tolerance, so a vector very close to zero but not *actually* zero will return `true` if you compare it to a zero vector with `==`. The `.Equals()` method only returns `true` for an exact match.

For quaternions, you have a somewhat easier time, in that any valid quaternion will have a non-zero value. ie. `Quaternion.Dot(rotation, rotation)` should be close to 1.0 — even for `Quaternion.identity`, which is (0, 0, 0, 1) (in x, y, z, w order).

So if you ever read an all-zero quaternion (like `default`), you can be sure that was not a deliberately set value, and needs to be overridden.

The difference between an all-zero quaternion and a valid one is much larger than the tolerance used in the `==` operator, so you don't strictly need the `.Equals()` method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Quaternion? rotation = null;
Vector3? position = null;

then you can check if the value exit in savefile